# Soft spot for [something]?

Tags: word-choice, idioms

I always thought that "soft spot" is used for *living things*..

E.g.

1. soft spot for someone
2. soft spot for my pet dog
3. soft spot for the fishes in the pond

But I was wondering can it be used for *non-living things* as well.. for example:

1. He had a soft spot for numbers. *<- does it make sense ?*
2. He had a soft spot for counting. *<- what about this*
3. He had a soft spot for counting activities. *<- better or worse?*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Soft spot](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/soft+spot) actually has two common meanings, and both of them **can refer to inanimate objects.**

The first meaning is the one to which you refer - essentially, a **sentimental weakness** for something. This is often used with living creatures simply because a kitten/baby/whatever more often pulls on our heartstrings than, say, a rock does. But you could, for instance, be a hardcore metal fan who has a soft spot for country music.

The other meaning of soft spot is an actual weakness (of the unemotional variety). This is more often than not used for inanimate objects - a soft spot in the economic recovery plan, a soft spot in the offensive line, etc.

Comment: So a soft spot for numbers means he sucks at maths?

Comment: @Pacerier no, I don't think I'd ever say anyone has a "soft spot for math".  The second meaning refers usually to a weakness in a plan or system (a point where it is likely to break/fail).  However, the meaning of "sentimental weakness for something" is more often used, and in this sense, one would not generally use it with inanimate objects--it implies a rather strong emotion.  If you do, it's probably hyperbole: "I have a soft spot for ice cream."